# rerun a program and stringstream?

Tags: c++, stringstream, root-framework

I have this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>  
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;




void ProvaErrore() {

    string line, line1;
    char delim = ' ';
    ifstream myfile("DatiMemoria.txt");
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    vector<vector<double>> vettore(40);
    vector<double> risultato;

    while (getline(myfile, line1))
    {
        stringstream ss(line1);
        while (getline(ss, line, delim))
        {
            if (j == 12)
            {
                i++;
                j = 0;
            }
            if (j == 0)
            {
                if (line == 'p')
                {
                    risultato.push_back(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    risultato.push_back(1);
                }
            }
            if (j == 1)
            {
                if (line == 'x')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                }
            }
            if (j == 2)
            {
                if (line == 's')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                }
                if (line == 'y')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                }
                if (line == 'f')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                }
            }
            if (j == 3)
            {
                if (line == 'w')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                }
                if (line == 'n')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                }
            }
            if (j == 4)
            {
                if (line == 't')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                }
                if (line == 'f')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                }
            }
            if (j == 5)
            {
                if (line == 'l')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                }
                if (line == 'p')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                }
                if (line == 'n')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                }
                if (line == 'a')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                }
            }
            if (j == 6)
            {
                if (line == 'b')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                }
                if (line == 'n')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                }
            }
            if (j == 7)
            {
                if (line == 'k')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                }
                if (line == 'w')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                }
                if (line == 'n')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                }
                if (line == 'p')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                }
            }
            if (j == 8)
            {
                if (line == 'c')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                }
                if (line == 'e')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                }
            }
            if (j == 9)
            {
                if (line == 'k')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                }
                if (line == 'n')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                }
            }
            if (j == 10)
            {
                if (line == 's')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                }
                if (line == 'v')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                }
            }
            if (j == 11)
            {
                if (line == 'g')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                }
                if (line == 'u')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                }
            }
            j++;

        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 14; j++)
        {
            cout << vettore[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

}
```

With that txt file:

```
e x y w t a b n c n s g
p x s w t p n k e k s g
p x y n t p n k e n v u
p x y w t p n w e k s g
p x s w t p n n e n s g
p x y w t p n w e n s g
p x y w t p n k e n s g
p x y w t p n k e k s g
p x y n t p n p e k v u
e f f n f n n p e n v u
p f y n t p n k e k v u
p x s w t p n w e n s g
p f y n t p n k c n v u
p x y n t p n n e n v u
p x s w t p n k e n s g
p f s n t p n p e k v u
p x y n t p n p e n v u
p x y w t p n n e k s g
p x y n t p n k e k v u
e x f n f n n n e k v u
e x s w t l b k c k s g
e x f n f n n k e n v u
e x y w t l b w c k s g
p f y n t p n p e n v u
e x s w t l b n c n s g
e x y w t a b w c n s g
e x y w t a b k c n s g
e x y w t l b k c k s g
e x f n f n n p e k v u
p x y n t p n n e k v u
e f f n f n n k e k v u
e x s w t l b w c n s g
e f f n f n n k e n v u
e x f n f n n n e n v u
e x s w t a b k c n s g
e f f n f n n p e k v u
e x f n f n n p e n v u
e x y w t l b n c k s g
e x f n f n n k e k v u
p x y w t p n n e n s g
```

It is a simple program useful for data analysis. I have a file with 40 lines. Each line is a mushroom and each column is a feature for example the first one is edible or poisonus. I want to read that file and transform the letter in numbers (in bynary numbers) in order to put them in a neural network. Normally I do this with python but I wanted to try in c++

When I first run it everything is fine. But if I try to rerun it I have this error:

```
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::stringstream' (aka 'basic_stringstream<char, char_traits<char>,
      allocator<char> >')
                stringstream ss(line1);
                             ^  ~~~~~
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\include\sstream:531:14: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>,
      allocator<char> >') to 'ios_base::openmode' (aka 'int') for 1st argument
    explicit basic_stringstream(ios_base::openmode _Mode = ios_base::in | ios_base::out)
             ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\include\sstream:539:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>,
      allocator<char> >') to 'std::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >' for 1st
      argument
    basic_stringstream(basic_stringstream&& _Right) : _Mybase(&_Stringbuffer) { // construct by moving _Right
    ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.20.27508\include\sstream:562:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>,
      allocator<char> >') to 'const std::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >' for
      1st argument
    basic_stringstream(const basic_stringstream&) = delete;
```

Why?

Comment: When you say "run" and "rerun" I really think you mean *"build"*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us, because the code snippet you show shouldn't give the errors you get.

Comment: It would probably be useful to post more of your code. I'm not seeing anything wrong with your example (other than the way you're dealing with file input, but I might just not be seeing the full picture).

Comment: Does it make any difference to declare `ss` as an `std::istringstream` or explicitly  pass the open mode? It seems that MSVC can't  deduce the [right overload of the constructor(3)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/basic_stringstream).

Comment: @DrakeJohnson I have edited the question with my program that gives error, not the first time but the second time I run it

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  I have edited the question with my program that gives error, not the first time but the second time I run it

Comment: @MementoMori It would also help a lot of you explained what exactly you're trying to do with your script. Right now all I'm looking at is a bunch of nested if statements and a weird way of reading in files.

Comment: @Bob__ I have edited the question with the program. It seems that doesn't make difference

Comment: Note that the posted code doesn't have an `#include <string>`.

Comment: @MementoMori This is not a [repro]. It is neither complete (doesn't have a `main`), nor is it minimal (all the `if`s are irrelevant to the error). Please read the link again carefully. Your code is however at least missing includes for `<string>` and `<fstream>` and there are other clear errors. For example you cannot compare strings and character literals with `==`.

Comment: The code you show results in two categories of errors when I try to build it: The first is that `ifstream` is an incomplete type, because you don't include `<fstream>`. The second category which results in a *lot* of errors is that you compare a string (`line`) with *single characters* (like in e.g. `line == 'p'`).

Comment: I have understood that the code is not minimal and I'm trying to fix it. But the code worked perfectly for me the first time that i run it. I'm using root cern with viisual studio 2019 but I think that it is Always c++, this is why I have not main. The file name is ProvaErrore

Comment: @MementoMori It is hard to believe that this code ever worked. While code *may* still work if includes are missing, comparing `std::string`s to `char`s (character literals) was always ill-formed, assuming you didn't define an overload for that manually. It can not have run on any C++ compiler.

Comment: Actually, (without knowing much about ROOT, but looking at the documentation): It seems `TString` has constructor overloads for both `std::string` and `char`. Given that the documentation doesn't mention that they are `explicit`, if you include this `TString` class the `==` comparison between `std::string` and `char` might work since it will call the `operator==(const TString&, const TString&)` overload, implicitly converting both arguments. This would not work in standard C++. You should probably add to your question that you are using ROOT and how exactly you are using it.

Comment: @walnut the code works, so probably is what you are talking about

Comment: @MementoMori You need to explain exactly how you were using the code when it worked and how you are using it now. ROOT is quite different from just standard C++. I suggest you add the `root-framework` tag and explain how you are using it.

Comment: @walnut Thank walnut, i don't know that there is that difference, I use and Always used Root to program i don't know also that there is root tag. I will edit the question soon

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to

```
#include <fstream>
```

the header of [`std::ifstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream)

---

```
 if (line == 'p')
```

doesn't work, as `line` is a `std::string`. Here you want

```
 if (line[0] == 'p')
```

to receive the target character. So replace all `line ==` instances with `line[0] ==`

---

As an advice, try to improve the quality of your code. You could achieve that by diving your structure into sections and use functions to handle each task.

also, you [shouldn't `use namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

---

full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>  
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


void ProvaErrore() {

    string line, line1;
    char delim = ' ';
    ifstream myfile("DatiMemoria.txt");
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    vector<vector<double>> vettore(40);
    vector<double> risultato;

    while (getline(myfile, line1))
    {
        stringstream ss(line1);
        while (getline(ss, line, delim))
        {
            if (j == 12)
            {
                i++;
                j = 0;
            }
            if (j == 0)
            {
                if (line[0] == 'p')
                {
                    risultato.push_back(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    risultato.push_back(1);
                }
            }
            if (j == 1)
            {
                if (line[0] == 'x')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                }
            }
            if (j == 2)
            {
                if (line[0] == 's')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                }
                if (line[0] == 'y')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                }
                if (line[0] == 'f')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                }
            }
            if (j == 3)
            {
                if (line[0] == 'w')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                }
                if (line[0] == 'n')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                }
            }
            if (j == 4)
            {
                if (line[0] == 't')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                }
                if (line[0] == 'f')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                }
            }
            if (j == 5)
            {
                if (line[0] == 'l')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                }
                if (line[0] == 'p')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                }
                if (line[0] == 'n')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                }
                if (line[0] == 'a')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                }
            }
            if (j == 6)
            {
                if (line[0] == 'b')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                }
                if (line[0] == 'n')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                }
            }
            if (j == 7)
            {
                if (line[0] == 'k')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                }
                if (line[0] == 'w')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                }
                if (line[0] == 'n')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                }
                if (line[0] == 'p')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                }
            }
            if (j == 8)
            {
                if (line[0] == 'c')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                }
                if (line[0] == 'e')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                }
            }
            if (j == 9)
            {
                if (line[0] == 'k')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                }
                if (line[0] == 'n')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                }
            }
            if (j == 10)
            {
                if (line[0] == 's')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                }
                if (line[0] == 'v')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                }
            }
            if (j == 11)
            {
                if (line[0] == 'g')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(0);
                }
                if (line[0] == 'u')
                {
                    vettore[i].push_back(1);
                }
            }
            j++;

        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 14; j++)
        {
            cout << vettore[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

output:

```
0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0
1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1
0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1
1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but no, I have it.

Comment: @MementoMori if you solved your own problem, add an answer so that people with the same problem will have a solution.

Comment: I don't know, probably it is a bit different. See my last comment above. The first time that I run it it is fine no errors. In line i have symple letters. I have tried with cout<<line<<endl; and it shows me only single letters.

Comment: If you try to rerun it a second time, or rebuild as they have said above, is it fine for you?

Comment: @MementoMori yes it works for me, as the output I posted shows. make sure to `#include <fstream>` this time. or just copy the code, I posted the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to do file IO by, first, splitting a file into lines and, second, splitting each line by spaces (which, in your example, splits them into 1-character-long strings). Instead, you could just take a range-based loop through every other character (especially since every line has the same number of characters). Opening the file like the following would avoid using `std::stringstream` altogether:

```cpp
std::string current_line;
/* vectors here */
std::ifstream myfile("DatiMemoria.txt");

// You had int j(char_num) = 0, i(line_num) = 0;
// I renamed them to make it clear what they're for
// Also, `char_num` is not initialized until later
unsigned line_num = 0;
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while (std::getline(myfile, current_line))
    {
        for (int char_num = 0; char_num <= 2 * (12 - 1); char_num += 2)
        {
            // use:
            //     current_line.at(char_num)
            // to get the current character. Then do what you need
            // to with that character. Then, the loop will move to 
            // the next character.
        }
        line_num++;
    }
}
```

However, just so I'm not ignoring your question, it seems your compiler is wanting to use a different constructor for `stringstream` than the one that takes in the `const std::string&`. In fact, if you look at your error log, it only shows 3 possible constructors. This is why I tend to try to avoid using `stringstream`.

If you're dead set on using `stringstream`, though, you can just create the stream and then push the string into it in two separate steps.

```cpp
std::string str;
std::stringstream sstrm;
sstrm << str;
```

Or, if strings are giving you errors,

```cpp
std::string str;
std::stringstream sstrm;
sstrm << str.c_str();
```

I can't imagine any sane compiler having a problem with that.